# Eloquent Route implicit binding Laravel 5.6 isn't working

Tags: php, laravel, binding, eloquent

I have tried to develop an application and I'd like to use route binding, but something is wrong and I don't know what it is. Plz, look code below and help me what it is wrong.

Route

```
|        | PATCH    | api/v1/filial/{filial}                  |      | Genesis\Base\Filial\Controllers\FilialController@update                    | auth:api   |
```

Model

```
class Filial extends Model{

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = "filiais"; ...
```

Controller

```
class FilialController extends BaseFormController{...
    public function update(FilialRequest $request, Filial $filial){
       dd($filial);
    }...
```

And then the output comes as a model empty. I don't know what it is wrong, parameter's, Model, Uri all these things matches. I'm using Laravel 5.6 since the beginning of this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure you have everything setup properly, in your `kernel.php` you should have:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ...
];
```

You also need to ensure you have the bindings middleware in your routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['bindings'], function() {
    // routes
}
```

If that still isn't working I would opt to look into [explicit route binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding):

> To register an explicit binding, use the router's model method to
>   specify the class for a given parameter. You should define your
>   explicit model bindings in the boot method of the 
>   RouteServiceProvider class:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('filial', App\Filial::class);
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, with your tip I found the problem, In kernel.php the 'bindings' midleware it was to 'api' but I was using 'auth:api', so, what I did it was add 'api' to my routes, however IDK whether it is the best way to do it, or add in kernel.php something like
`'auth:api' => [
            'bindings',
        ],`
in $middlewareGroups. What do you think?

Comment: I think any option is fine, personally I just have most of my routes within a group like in my code sample above but putting it in `$middlewareGroups` seems like an equally good option!